# Use a flutter charts widget inside of a expanded widget

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, charts, flutter-layout

Here is a representation of the UI I would like to make (excuse the crudeness):

[image: Wireframe of app]

I intend for the welcome back message, the latest reading message, and the chart to all be in a column, with the chart being expanded to fill the entire screen. Here is my component tree and the build method as of now:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: _data == null || _data.length == 0
            ? Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No data, add data to get started',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              )
            : Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Welcome Back",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Your latest reading was ${_data.last.systolic}/${_data.last.diastolic}.",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  BPLineChart(data: _data),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
```

However, if I wrap the BPLineChart with a expanded widget, I get this ui error in my console

```
I/flutter (11080): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (11080): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (11080): RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter (11080): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter (11080): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
```

and this in the ui:

[image: Screenshot of error on device]

Is there any way to wrap a flutter charts widget with an expanded widget?

Comment: This happens when you wrap the BPLineChart in expanded?

Comment: Yes, it is the same with any chart from the flutter charts library

Comment: Which package are you using for showing LineChart ?

Comment: The 'default' charting library from google [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_charts)

Comment: Is this widget inside of another widget?  If it is, can you show the code for that widget, also?

Comment: No, my chart is just by itself. I believe the chart itself is trying to use as much height as possible, thus resulting in it having an infinite height as it is unbounded. My guess is that a solution would have to limit the height and width of the chart, but in a way that is not hardcoded (like wrapping the chart in a sized box).